# What are the possible ways to play RTSP live stream on Web?

Tags: laravel, opencv3.0, rtsp, live-streaming

What are the possible ways we can play a live stream (RTSP) on the web browser, without using any video player plugin like VLC or VXG players?

I have a web application written with Laravel framework. The application is to play live stream from IP cameras. Using the video player plugins could work, but it has high latency. Also, it is not reliable. After running for some time, it will crash without any useful error message.

I tried to use opencv.js but failed. The VideoCapture function does not accept URL (but in its documentation it can. Perhaps in opencv.js it is different.)

Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

No options available. Web browsers can not open sockets directly. The only option for getting data into a browser are HTTP, web sockets or webrtc.